Pipewire conflicts with SPDIF input
Fresh install of Ubuntu Studio 24.04. All hardware and softare worked perfect on 20.04.
The soundcard is a M-Audio 1010LT PCI where the SPDIF input is activated with an external ADC.
With Pipewire bridge to Jack activated this setup has a sample rate conflict (or clock conflict) with recordings heavy distorted. Without the bridge we are back to normal. All sample rates are set to 48000.
Any workaround for this? External sample rate clocks or SPDIF not compatible with Pipewire?
